# Encrypt in frontend and decrypt once it reaches backend

Tags: javascript, vue.js, encryption, nestjs, rsa

What would be the most secure way to do so?

So far I tried providing the same public key for every user which automatically encrypts the data sent over a https request to my backend.

For that reason, people with enough knowledge can get the json payload before its encrypted and encrypt it by themselves on their end and send it over my server.

The most ideal case would be so the client side only has access to the public key while the server can view both user's private key and public key.

I'm currently using RSA for this
Frameworks in use: VueJS and NestJS

Comment: What is your threat model? SSL/https is enough to prevent eavesdropping. And you can't prevent users from sending whatever payloads they want. Even if you add some additional encryption in your javascript, a malicious actor can just remove that logic.

Comment: I don't know how to explain it clearly. But sensitive data is going to be sent from the frontend to the backend, possible sniffers or custom tools could read the data in plaintext and make bad use of it.

Comment: @psjason if you are using SSL/HTTPS no sniffer can read the data, let alone modify it. Don't try to implement this delicate security concept on your own, you'd go crazy :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The web browser belongs to the user. It is completely under their control. Anything you do in the browser can be inspected and manipulated by the user.

You can encrypt data during transmission to protect it from *third-parties* with HTTPS.

You can't make the user's browser compensate for you not trusting the user.

Comment: I understand that the browser belongs to the user and that they can modify the data at their will, however maybe this is just from my point of view but sending plain text data such as passwords or emails from frontend to backend doesn't really fulfill a requirement I'm trying to meet. I see services like protonmail using that sort of stuff for their login and register page.

Comment: I refer you to the second paragraph of my answer. Use HTTPS. The data will be encrypted.

Comment: That makes sense, I'm aware that the requests sent through HTTPS are encrypted and can't be sniffed, I'm just thinking of this as an additional layer of security so that possible intruders can't just access the plain text data and get the users email or password entered on login.

Comment: Not sure if i'm being confusing, but by plain text data i'm refering to the json payloads sent to the backend. Excuse me for that.

Comment: If the intruder has got somewhere where they can sniff the data before the browser encrypts it for sending over HTTPS, then they've got somewhere where they can sniff the data before any extra encryption you do takes place.

Comment: If the JSON payloads are sent over HTTPS then they are encrypted.

Comment: That answers it, thanks for the input.